# Date time convertion with daylight saving

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, datetime-conversion

I am using following code to convert date time between time zones

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(site.TimeZone);
returnTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Parse(time.ToString()), timeZone);
```

The daylight saving adjustment for the CST timezone happened on 12th March. On that day it gave an error as

> The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time.  For example, when the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped is invalid

How can I change my date time conversion which support day light saving

Comment: What is the value of `time`, and is it supposed to be representing a time in CST, or perhaps something else such as UTC?

Comment: You could fix it by always working in UTC and keeping any conversions to local time as late as possible so that no further conversions/processing are attempted on local times. Since every UTC value *can* be mapped to your local time (albeit sometimes with an ambiguous output) you'll never end up working with an invalid time.

Comment: If there is any DateTime then consider using DateTimeOffset.

Comment: You should consider using NodaTime.  It is much richer in functionality than .NET's DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and fixed all of them using this easy to use alternative:

[Noda Time "A better date and time API for .NET"](http://nodatime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach would be to convert to UTC first and then to target timezone. While converting to UTC also check if time passed in is ambiguous, you may need to adjust for that, check the following [How to: Resolve Ambiguous times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384269(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to know the TimeZone of the source time value - that can be used to determine if the time is ambiguous. If not ambiguous convert to UTC via the source TimeZone by checking if it is standard time (apply the base UTC offset of the TimeZone) or daylight time (apply the non-base UTC offset) - the UTC offsets, ambiguous check and daylight check can be done via the TimeZoneInfo. If ambiguous you can either assume that the time is standard time or have an alternative means to specify if it is daylight time - once determined use the offset values as previously. Then use the target TimeZone to convert from UTC.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.